# Mongoose sort by array of dates (today + future)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I need help with a bit more complex version of sorting than usual. So I have `times: [Date]` field in scheme. Let's say my DB has 2 items with these fields:

- a) `time: [ "2022-12-28T18:00:00.000+00:00", "2023-01-04T18:00:00.000+00:00" ]`.
- b) `time: [ "2022-12-30T18:00:00.000+00:00" ]`.

My query:

```
const today = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
...
.find({ times: { $gte: today } }).sort("times")
```

Because today is 2022-12-29, `.sort("times")` or `.sort({ times: 1 })` will sort events in a way, that item "a)" will be sorted first, because from "now" Dec 28 is closer than 30, so it works correctly.

What I want is to ignore dates that are 1+ days old. It should consider dates that are today and all in the future, but not yesterday or later in the past.

I thought about querying all items once per day to and removing all past dates, but I kind of want to keep them. Is there a solution with aggregation for this problem?

EDIT: added algorithm for sorting array of dates

```
export const sortDateByClosest = datesArray => {
    if (datesArray.length === 1) return datesArray;

    const today = new Date();
    const yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1));

    const sorted = datesArray.sort((a, b) => {
        const distanceA = Math.abs(today - a);
        const distanceB = Math.abs(today - b);
        return distanceA - distanceB;
    });

    // remove times that were before yesterday
    return sorted.filter(d => d - yesterday > 0);
};
```

Comment: When the sort algorithm compares two date arrays, which shall count as the lesser one? Can you state that comparison rule more precisely?

Comment: It should be basically the usual date sorting algorithm but it should ignore past dates. As a simplified example, we may sort by future dates, ignoring everything that is less than `new Date()`

Comment: The "usual date sorting" compares two _dates_, but your sorter has to compare two _arrays of dates_. How?

Comment: updated question. the function leaves in arr[0] the closest item today or in the future

Comment: The function `sortDateByClosest` sorts _one array of dates_, but the database statement `.find({ times: { $gte: today } }).sort("times")` must somehow sort rows _by arrays of dates_. These are two different things. Probably you want to sort _by the closest date in the date array_. But this requires collaboration between the database and your Node.js function.

Comment: Mongoose supports sorting by arrays, so `.find({ times: { $gte: today } }).sort("times")` works correctly with arrays of dates. The code above works, it just has a flaw that I described

Answer (score 0):

I think it works You want to ignore 1+ days older dates then you need to use aggregation like this:

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([ { $unwind: '$times' },
  {
    "$match": {
      'times': {
        '$gte': today, 
       }
     }
  }, {
    $sort : {
      times: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't :(

Comment: am edited now can you try now

Comment: nop, returns empty array

Comment: Try unwind first, then match, then sort.  Note that there is not way for the sort to be aided by an index, so this will be an in-memory sort every time, and it won't scale well.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation be like:

```
    { $unwind: "$times" },
    {
        $match: {
            times: { "$gte": today }
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            times: 1,
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            times: { $push: "$times" },
            otherStuff: { $first: "$otherStuff" },
            ...
        }
    },
```

But it doesn't show very good results in terms of scalability